# Free InstallShield alternative?

Tags: installation, msi

What is the best free, simple alternative to InstallShield or WISE for creating installation packages? My needs are pretty simple, just 1 file to install with a couple dependencies. I will be using it every once in a blue moon, so I need something simple so I don't have to retrain every time I want to use it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net) is really good. And you don't even have to know how to use it if you use the Eclipse plugin :) The wizard will do it all for you. Of course, it doesn't create MSIs, so if that really is a hard requirement you can't use it.

The only alternative I know for MSI building is [WIX](http://wix.sf.net). I hear it's good, but it's also going to be more complex than NSIS.